# Rails 3 - join table not updated when creating new HABTM association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many, join

I've spent the last three days on this and I can't find any answer anywhere.
I'm trying to learn Rails, and I started with what seemed a pretty easy application.

I have 2 models:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

  attr_accessible :title

end
```

and

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :albums

  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name

end
```

I also created the join table

```
create_table "albums_users", :id => false
    t.integer "album_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
```

My users/show.html.erb file contains a form

```
<%= form_for([@user, @user.albums.build]) do |f| %>
```

When this form is sent, it calls my album#create controller

```
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @album = @user.albums.cre(params[:album])  
    @album.save
  end
```

This creates a new album but doesn't create the entry in the join table.

When looking at the parameters hash sent when submitting the form, I have

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "commit"=>"Create Album", "user_id"=>"1", "authenticity_token"=>"XNCPLYWQRzjpuQfjqbR7XuhMjr5iRzjLiqXpqZ4spFo=", "album"=>{"event"=>"title"=>"My Title"}}
```

And the SQL request doesn't use the user_id value from the parameter hash

> SQL (3.4ms)  INSERT INTO "albums" ("title", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["title", "My Title"],["user_id", nil]]

I tried adding a hidden_field to my form with the user_id but then I get this error

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user_id
```

Can someone explain me what is wrong with my models and my association?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you want to be using HABTM? If so, you generally don't use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with a HABTM relationship...

Comment: It also looks like your albums model has a user_id property. Check your schema.db file, should it be there?

Comment: Would a has_many relationship be easier to deal with? There's a user_id property in my albums model. Shouldn't be there?

Comment: Well that depends, what is the actual relationship? Does one album have many users? And does one user have many albums?

Comment: Yes one album can have many users and one user can have many albums. I removed the user_id property from my album model with the same result...

Comment: Can you post your schema.db file?

Comment: Also remove the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and the `attr_accessible :album_attributes/:user_attributes` from both models

Comment: Doesn't change anything. How does rail know it has to update the join table? Just from the HABTM relationship declaration? Shouldn't it throw an error when I save my album and it doesn't have a user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use plurals for has_many associations
2. Build the album directly within the user's albums

   ```
   @album = @user.album.create(params[:album])
   ```

Comment: Ok, using plural for the association solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The user_id is not part of the album-subhash of the params hash, so there is not possibility that the user is added when the album gets saved.

A simple solution is this:

```
def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @album = @user.album.build(params[:album])  
    @album.save
end
```

Comment: The user_id is still not part of the album subhash `Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"XNCPLYWQRzjpuQfjqbR7XuhMjr5iRzjLiqXpqZ4spFo=", "commit"=>"Create Album", "album"=>{""title"=>"My Title"}, "user_id"=>"1", "utf8"=>"✓"}`